# Error "no module named 'tkinter'" when running app made using buildozer on android, even though i don`t use or call the module

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

i'm developing an Android app for the first time, and since i'm familiar with Python i decided to use Kivy and buildozer to develop and deploy it. When i run my Python code in windows "everything" works fine (i don`t actually know if everything works as there are features only available for Android). In the other hand, after getting the .apk file from buildozer and running it either on my phone or in a virtual Android machine from AndroidStudio the app crashes as soon as it starts. When checking the Logcat logs i identified a python error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'" (even though that was the first time i knew the existence of such module lol).

Edit: In short, the app crashes as soon as it starts running in Android. Checking the logs reveals that this is caused by a module not being recognized, which is `tkinter` although that module is not even used.

Many thanks in advance to anyone that helps :D

Below, the part of the Logcat logs that i`ve deemed relevant to the error:

```
2022-10-28 23:26:17.717  5466-5502  python                  org.test.astravamapp                 I  Initialized python
2022-10-28 23:26:17.718  5466-5502  python                  org.test.astravamapp                 I  AND: Init threads
.
.
.
2022-10-28 23:26:17.746  5466-5502  python                  org.test.astravamapp                 I  Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
2022-10-28 23:26:17.746  5466-5502  python                  org.test.astravamapp                 I  AND: Ran string
2022-10-28 23:26:17.746  5466-5502  python                  org.test.astravamapp                 I  Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
2022-10-28 23:26:17.764  5466-5502  python                  org.test.astravamapp                 I  Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-10-28 23:26:17.764  5466-5502  python                  org.test.astravamapp                 I    File "/content/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 2, in <module>
2022-10-28 23:26:17.765  5466-5502  python                  org.test.astravamapp                 I    File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
2022-10-28 23:26:17.766  5466-5502  python                  org.test.astravamapp                 I    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/turtle.py", line 107, in <module>
2022-10-28 23:26:17.768  5466-5502  python                  org.test.astravamapp                 I  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
2022-10-28 23:26:17.768  5466-5502  python                  org.test.astravamapp                 I  Python for android ended.
2022-10-28 23:26:17.790  5466-5502  HostConnection          org.test.astravamapp                 D  createUnique: call
2022-10-28 23:26:17.791  5466-5502  HostConnection          org.test.astravamapp                 D  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x778c61e75950, tid 5502
2022-10-28 23:26:17.795  5466-5502  HostConnection          org.test.astravamapp                 D  HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_queue_submit_with_commands ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma ANDROID_EMU_hwc_multi_configs GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2022-10-28 23:26:17.828  5466-5466  libc                    org.test.astravamapp                 A  Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x777f74591ad0 in tid 5466 (est.astravamapp), pid 5466 (est.astravamapp)
2022-10-28 23:26:18.154   605-2422  ActivityManager         system_process                       I  Process org.test.astravamapp (pid 5466) has died: fg  TOP 
2022-10-28 23:26:18.154   605-2370  WindowManager           system_process                       I  WIN DEATH: Window{c1600b2 u0 org.test.astravamapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
```

Seeing this i tried solving the issue by adding tk to the buildozer.spec file and importing tkinter from the main.py script. But the issue persists. Another thing i noticed was that the error ocurrs when python is that the issue happens when the machine runs code in /python3/Lib/turtle.py (another module i had never heard of)

I also discard the issue being a caps issue confusing Tkinter for tkinter, which i've read in multiple questions, but only lowercase tkinter is present in my code and files, and i'm effectively in python3, acknowledged by the Logcat error too, "File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/turtle.py""

I had added the buildozer.spec file but stackoverflow considered it too spammy, so i add the requirements line, which i think should suffice:

```
requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd,plyer,pillow,tk
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Edited, hope it clears out the problem

Comment: You don't need or want tkinter, it won't work on android. If you don't understand why your code is trying to use it, post a minimal runnable example and the full logcat output you're interpreting.